# Tornado Create a Secure Cookie with expiry time less than 1 day

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I'm using `Tornado`'s [`Secure Cookie`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/security.html) functionality to implement user session. The `set_secure_cookie` function enables us to create a Cookie where lower limit for cookie expiry can be set to 1 day. Now, I need to expire these secure cookies in one hour. Can I achieve this easily?

One solution is to append a timestamp with the cookie value. For example, if the cookie value is my user's ID (e.g. `1`), then I can create a cookie like `1_{current datetime}`. When validating later, I can split the cookie value and check if the date-time after the `underscore character` is not less than 1 hour before current time. This sounds acceptable to me as Tornado's Secure Cookies can not be modified by the user.

However, are there any elegant solution than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use decimal days. For 12 hours, 0.5 days, etc

What the actual code does is

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=expires_days)
```

And timedelta transforms everything to seconds, so a decimal date of 0.4 is almost an hour.

You should also pay attention when reading the cookie with `get_secure_cookie`. You should pass the same value to `max_age_days` when reading it.

Comment: Note that whenever you modify the expiration time you should generally also change `max_age_days` when you call `get_secure_cookie` (the two have slightly different meanings; `max_age_days` on the get side is more important since a user could save an old cookie and reuse it past its expiration time). Fractional values work here too.

Comment: @BenDarnell If the cookie which I set to have validity for 1 hour, and still call get_secure_cookie with no parameter (which means max 31 age days), it can detect that the cookie is invalid (past 1 hour). Am I correct?

Comment: @BenDarnell I created a cookie with one hour validity. But the cookie seems still valid after one hour! Do I need to pass "one hour" value for the argument  `max_age_days` also?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you change `expires` or `expires_days` when setting the cookie, you should also change `max_age_days` when reading it.

Comment: @Tasos Can you please add in your answer that we need to pass "1 hour" as value for `max_age_days` parameter when calling `get_secure_cookie`? Only passing value to `set_secure_cookie` does not work. It only sends the expiry information as cookie header so that the browser can expire the cookie.

Comment: it would be helpful to put actual code snippets that show things in action